# interface forwarding from member variable using C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

How do I say:

```
template<typename T>
class X {
  // if T has method x(), define
  //   Y x() { return t.x() }

  T t;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define it.

If `X::x` isn't called, then `T::x` doesn't have to exist either.  If `X::x` is called and `T::x` doesn't exist, the error message will point to the use of `X::x`.  Most compilers would use wording along the lines of: "Unknown identifier `x` while compiling `Y X<Something>::x(void)` within this context: *whatever called X::x() for a Something that doesn't support it*".

EDIT: Since you're using C++0x, by all means use decltype:

```
template<typename T>
class Forwards {
     T t;
public:
    decltype(this->t.x()) x() { return this->t.x(); }
};
```

I'm not 100% sure about whether to use `decltype(T::x())`, `decltype(t.x())`, or `decltype(this->t.x())`, but I'm pretty sure this should work.  If `t` doesn't supply `x`, then the `Forwards::x()` function wouldn't be able to be instantiated.  This still isn't perfect forwarding, since you need to know the argument list a-priori, but now you can deal with return type variation.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the pattern.  Thanks for confirming.  (I guess this means that you can't forward two functions with conflicting return types though.)

Comment: C++0x brings `decltype` which will enable that.  I don't know any non-invasive way to do it in C++03 though.

Comment: @Neil G: What is it that you really want to achieve? A single class cannot have more than one method differing only in the return type, but you can have different return values in different instantiations of the template (and/or different specializations)

Comment: @David Rodríguez: I have a set of classes X_1, X_2, ...  I have a template class Y<T>, which I apply to X_i, and which adds members and methods.  (Y<X_i> has a member variable x of type X_i.)  Some of the X_i implement interface Z.  I would like Y<X_i> to implement interface Z through its member x if and only if X_i implements Z.  That makes sense, right?  Now suppose that there's a second interface W, which has a function with the same name and signature as in Z, but with a different return value.  Now it's impossible to conditionally forward both interfaces.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I am using C++0x.

Comment: using "this" in the return type will fail. Instead you can use `t.x()` directly (unqualified lookup will find it). "this" is only visible in member function bodies or constructor initializer lists.